# Hosting a .net core 1.1 webapp on a windows 10 system

Tags: c#, iis, windows-10, asp.net-core-1.1

Not sure where to ask this but figure someone might be able to shed some light on it. I am new to the whole .net core stuff and have been learning and taking some online classes. My question is this I am trying to self host a webapp/site what I am making in visual studios 2015 in C# using .net core 1.1. I have the app up and running locally when I run it in IIS Express everything works fine. What I cant seem to figure out is how to publish this to my windows 10 system. I have been digging around the web an came across a few articles but even following there steps it seems i cant get this thing to publish. Has anyone here run into the same situation and have gotten it working or know what i need/how to configure windows 10 and IIS to get this running ? Thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the guide for configuring Kestrel to use IIS as a reverse proxy:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/

Note that you **do not** want to use Kestrel by itself as it has not been hardened against attacks yet.

---

That said, what you are trying to do is not likely to work. For starters; IIS running on a desktop OS is limited to 10 concurrent connections, so having a real live website is just not going to happen. Furthermore, you need a static IP for the server to be consistently reachable via DNS. That service usually will cost you quite a bit (more than just using shared hosting).

The easiest way to host this would likely be in a free Azure Web App.

Comment: ah did not know about the 10 concurrent connections. as for the static IP I already have that paid more for it from the ISP. Yeah i see a lot of stuff about using azure but rather not have to pay them to host it. so with the OS then i am assuming i would need a server OS to get around that limitation? Also thanks for the info looking into the kestrel stuff.

Comment: @B.North Yes; you will need a Windows Server license